# Regular expression for number + white space + specific word(s)

Tags: ios, regex, swift, string

I want to create a regular expression that finds specific words and the numbers before them.

Example: if the words are "apples" and "plums" in "Annie has 20 apples and 3 plums." I need the range of "20 apples" and the range of "3 plums".

Answer (score 5):

The following regex appears to be what you're after:

```
\d+\s+\w+
```

https://regex101.com/r/HNFdrC/1

Matches "`20 apples`" and "`3 plums`" in the string:

> Annie has 20 apples and 3 plums.

Comment: That's actually surprisingly beautiful for being regex.